# How can I display views using autolayout constraints in Xcode playground?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, swift-playground

I am trying to display views configured with **autolayout** constraints in XCode **playground**, but it doesn't seem to work. It's like playground ignores the constraints completely, and I can't find information about this issue anywhere.

Here's the code I tried:

```
let view = UIView()
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 200)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

let label = UILabel() // I can only see the label if I set a frame
         // UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50))
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
label.text = "I am a label"
label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
view.addSubview(label)

let views = ["label":label]
let options = NSLayoutFormatOptions(0)

let cs1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "H:|-[label]-|", options: options, metrics: nil, views:views )

let cs2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "V:|-[label]-|", options: options, metrics: nil, views:views )

view.addConstraints(cs1)
view.addConstraints(cs2)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Import xcplayground and then use XCPShowView

Comment: You might need a call to layoutIfNeeded

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Yes, it seems that I need both things. You can write a reply if you want so I can mark it.

Comment: Great to hear it! Posted an answer, have a great evening

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That being said you can use the `liveView` property of `PlaygroundPage` to preview your UI.

```
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myLiveView
```

Here's a [link](http://whoisryannystrom.com/2015/03/30/Visual-Playground-Unit-Tests/) that expands on this further.

If its not working you may need to trigger a `layoutIfNeeded` but that shouldn't really solve the issue since Swift 4

Also, include `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on your view. Like:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

myLiveView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myLiveView
```

Comment: Thanks! `import XCPlayground` and `XCPShowView("view",view)` is exactly what I needed.

Comment: In Xcode 8, you'll get deprecated warnings. use `import PlaygroundSupport` and `Playground.current.liveView = view`.

Comment: I'm confused as to where the `layoutIfNeeded` would be needed. Mine's works without it. Can you show an example where using it would be a must?

Comment: Looks like it’s been fixed @Honey feel free to submit an edit if you want it updated :)

Answer (score 5):

The provided solutions were not useful for me. I wanted a view in which I could work with constraints. To achieve that I had to create a containerView with a CGRect base and adding constraints to it as well. Everything else was not successful. So I got a viewable base and was able to add views just with constraints.

Setup ContainerView:

```
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 600, height: 400))
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView

containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 600).isActive = true
containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
```

Place View in ContainerView with constraints:

```
let myView = UIView(frame: .zero)
myView.backgroundColor = .green
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

containerView.addSubview(myView)

myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

This creates this view:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My final code;

If you only see the yellow outer UIView then definitely need:

```
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

And to make sure view is updating change the text of the label

```
label.text = "I am a label3 "
```

FULL CODE

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333323/how-can-i-display-views-using-autolayout-constraints-in-xcode-playground/30336502#30336502




let view = UIView()
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

//-------------------------------------------------------------

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
//needed else label may not appear
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true


//-------------------------------------------------------------
//LABEL
//-------------------------------------------------------------
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,200, 50))
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

//TO FORCE REFRESH change text of label
label.text = "I am a label3 "

//add constraints
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

//COULDNT GET TO WORK
view.addSubview(label)


//--------------------------------------------------------------
//COMMENT OUT TO SEE LABEL with out constraints
//--------------------------------------------------------------
let views = ["label":label]
let options = NSLayoutFormatOptions(arrayLiteral:[])

let cs1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "H:|-[label]-|", options: options, metrics: nil, views:views )

let cs2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "V:|-[label]-|", options: options, metrics: nil, views:views )

view.addConstraints(cs1)
view.addConstraints(cs2)

//XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that now you need to do something like this:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let main = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 700))
main.backgroundColor = .blackColor()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = main

// now add views and constraints to main

main // display view
```

Comment: Its more polite to comment on the accepted question that the answer needs to be updated than to simply take away your vote and answer the question yourself.

Comment: Ok, Daniel, I can give your mark back. I just thought about people that quickly looks for the accepted answer.

Comment: I know, but its not possible for people to keep all their answers up to date and the default is always to sort by votes so its better practice to let the poster know:) Have a great day!