# How to apply autolayout constraints in a playground?

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift-playground

I want to work with Autolayout inside an Xcode playground, however I can't get a simple setup to work.

```
let red = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
red.backgroundColor = .red
red.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: red, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: red, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)

red.addConstraints([widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
```

However, when checking `red` after these lines have been executed, it still has a frame of `CGRect.zero` and `width` and `height` did not get updated.

[image]

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333323/how-can-i-display-views-using-autolayout-constraints-in-xcode-playground

Comment: Setting `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView` may be not enough. Try creating a view with a hardcoded frame and add `red` as subview.